# Files with spaces in file name in rshiny www directory

Tags: html, r, iframe, shiny

I have a question regarding embedding pdf or any other files for the matter within the shiny app. I have certain files (which cannot be renamed) with spaces in the file names, like, "report client 0056.pdf".
I have embedded them using tags$iframe in the shiny app.

The browser returns Error 409, Not Found, when I embed such files, but files without any space in the name work without any issue. When I inspect the html code in the browser, the spaces in the file names are encoded as %20, but the browser is not able to process that. Do you have any work around for this problem?

Here is the error:

> http://127.0.0.1:6323/report%20client%200056.pdf
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Here is the shiny script:

```
PDFfile="report client 0056.pdf"
output$view <- renderUI({
        tags$iframe(
        src=PDFfile,
        width="100%",
        height="1200px")
      })
```

Comment: Seems unlikely that it would be found at the root directory. You should indicate your OS and say what `file.exists("/report client 0056.pdf")` returns. My guess is FALSE.

Comment: I am running it using RStudio 64 bit in Windows 7 Professional. 

    `file.exists("www/report client 0056.pdf")
    [1] TRUE`

All other files in the same directory having file names with no spaces work perfectly.

Comment: ? Tried with: `PDFfile="report%20client%200056.pdf"` ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried using `PDFfile="report%20client%200056.pdf"`, but it throws out the same 409 error.